# Is it possible to call ConfirmationService from another Service

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I would like to declare an application wide PrimeNg   (i.e: inside app.component.html) and then being able to display it by calling ConfirmationService.confirm() from another service.
Please find the code HTML in app-component.html

```
<p-confirmDialog
[key]="mainDialog"
class="styleDialog"
[baseZIndex]="10000"
> </p-confirmDialog>
```

Then I create service dialogue.service.ts

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root', })    

  export class FooService{

  constructor(
  
   private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,`

    ) {}

  doSomeStuff() {

  this.confirmationService.confirm({
  key:'mainDialog',
  message: 'some message',
  header: 'Warning',
  icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
  acceptLabel: 'ok',
  rejectVisible: false,
  accept: () => {},
  });
}
 } `
```

--> But this does not working . Please Am i missing something ?

I would be grateful for Your response

Comment: What exactly does not work? What kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So the first problem is that you're using `key` as a directive (so `[key]`). It means that inside you've to write a property declared in the component. In this case you can use directly a string, so change your HTML in this way:

```
<p-confirmDialog key="mainDialog" class="styleDialog" [baseZIndex]="10000">
    Content
</p-confirmDialog>
```

Then, in you `app.module.ts` you should add as provider the `ConfirmationService`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
...
  ],
  imports: [
...
    ConfirmDialogModule
  ],
  providers: [ConfirmationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Lastly, I noticed that's an error in your `FooService`. I suppose it's related to your copy/paste on StackOverflow but yeah let me write it down too.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ConfirmationService} from 'primeng/api';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FooService {

  constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {
  }

  confirm(): void {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      key: 'mainDialog',
      message: 'some message',
      header: 'Warning',
      icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
      acceptLabel: 'ok',
      rejectVisible: false,
      accept: () => {
        console.log('accept');
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Don't forget to declare and call you `FooService.confirm` method where you need it. Let's suppose you need it in the `app.component.ts`, you'll have something like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FooService} from './foo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private fooService: FooService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fooService.confirm();
  }
}
```